# HTTP Status 404 -/Pracownik/

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jsp, maven

I working on that project for 2 days and i can't finde why it's doesn't work.

It is a typical CRUD web application using SPRING,HIBERNATE,MAVEN and Tomcat
**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                    WEB-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->



       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
              destroy-method="close" 
              p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              p:url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/studentDB" 
              p:username="postgres" 
              p:password="password" />

       <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

              <property name="packagesToScan">
                     <list>
                           <value>pl.kert.pracownik.model</value>
                     </list>
              </property>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                     <props>
                           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                     </props>
              </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
       </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="pl.kert.pracownik" />
</beans>
```

**serlvet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

       <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
              infrastructure -->

       <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
       <annotation-driven />
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
       <context:component-scan base-package="pl.kert.pracownik.controller" />

       <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /web-resources/** by efficiently serving
              up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
       <resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/resources/" />

       <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
              in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
       <beans:bean
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
              <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Praktyki</groupId>
  <artifactId>Pracownik</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Pracownik Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
              <java-version>1.8.0_11</java-version>
              <spring-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring-version>
              <hibernate-version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate-version>
              <apache-connection-pooling-version>1.4</apache-connection-pooling-version>
       </properties>
       <dependencies>
              <!-- Spring -->
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring-version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring-version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                     <version>${spring-version}</version>
              </dependency>

              <!-- Hibernate -->
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                     <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                     <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
              </dependency>

              <!--
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                     <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                     <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
              </dependency> 
              -->

              <!-- Apache's Database Connection Pooling -->
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                     <version>${apache-connection-pooling-version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                     <version>${apache-connection-pooling-version}</version>
              </dependency>

              <!-- Baza -->
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>

              <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
       <build>
          <plugins>

              <!-- Tomcat 7 plugin -->
              <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.0</version>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.9</version>
                  <configuration>
                       <additionalProjectnatures>
                           <projectnature>
                               org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature
                           </projectnature>
                       </additionalProjectnatures>
                       <additionalBuildcommands>
                           <buildcommand>
                               org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder
                           </buildcommand>
                       </additionalBuildcommands>
                       <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                       <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
       <repositories>
              <repository>
                     <id>java.net</id>
                     <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
              </repository>
       </repositories>
</project>
```

**pracownikForm.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:url var="actionUrl" value="save" />

<form:form id="pracownikForm" commandName="pracownik" method="post"
    action="${actionUrl}" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">

    <fieldset>
          <legend></legend>

          <div class="pure-control-group">
              <label for="imie">Imie</label>
              <form:input path="imie" placeholder="Imie pracownika" />
          </div>
          <div class="pure-control-group">
               <label for="nazwisko">Nazwisko</label>
               <form:input path="nazwisko" placeholder="Nazwisko" />
          </div>
          <div class="pure-control-group">
              <label for="email">"Email"</label>
              <form:input path="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          </div>
          <div class="pure-control-group">
              <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
              <form:input path="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" />
          </div>

          <form:input path="id" type="hidden" />
      </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

**listaPracownikow.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Lista Pracownikow</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/web-resources/css/pure-0.4.2.css"/>'>

<link rel="stylesheet"
       href='<c:url value="/web-resources/css/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"/>'>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
       href='<c:url value="/web-resources/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>'>
<style type="text/css">
  th {
       text-align: left
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
   <div style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div id="pracownikDialog" style="display: none;">
            <%@ include file="pracownikForm.jsp"%>
        </div>

        <h1>Lista Pracowników</h1>

        <button class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onclick="DodajPracownika()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Dodaj Pracownika
         </button>
         <br>
         <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered pure-table-striped">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th width="4%">ID Pracownika</th>
                  <th width="12%">Imie</th>
                  <th width="12%">Nazwisko</th>
                  <th width="12%">E-mail</th>
                  <th width="12%">Telefon</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <c:forEach items="${listaPracownikow}" var="pracownik" varStatus="loopCounter">
               <tr>
                   <td><c:out value="${loopCounter.count}" /></td>
                   <td><c:out value="${pracownik.imie}" /></td>
                   <td><c:out value="${pracownik.nazwisko}" /></td>
                   <td><c:out value="${pracownik.email}" /></td>
                   <td><c:out value="${pracownik.telefon}" /></td>

                   <td>
                     <nobr>
                        <button onclick="edytujPracwonika(${pracownik.id});"
                                class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
                             <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edycja
                        </button>

                        <a href="delete/${pracownik.id}" class="pure-button pure-button-primary"
                   onclick="return confirm('Czy jestes pewny, ze chcesz usunac tego pracownika?');">
                             <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Usun
                        </a>
                      </nobr>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>

     <!--  It is advised to put the <script> tags at the end of the document body so that they don't block rendering of the page -->

    <script type="text/javascript"
       src='<c:url value="/web-resources/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
       src='<c:url value="/web-resources/js/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"/>'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
       src='<c:url value="/web-resources/js/js-for-listaPracownikow.js"/>'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PracownikController.java**

```
package pl.kert.pracownik.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import pl.kert.pracownik.model.Pracownik;
import pl.kert.pracownik.service.PracownikService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pracownik")
public class PracownikController {

    @Autowired
    private PracownikService pracownikService;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/","/listaPracownikow"})
    public String listaPracownikow(Map<String,Object> map){
        map.put("pracownik", new Pracownik());

        map.put("listaPracownikow", pracownikService.listaPracownikow());

        return "/book/listaPracownikow";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/get/{pracownikId}")
    public String getPracownik(@PathVariable int pracownikId, Map<String, Object> map){

        Pracownik pracownik = pracownikService.getPracownik(pracownikId);

        map.put("pracownik", pracownik);

        return "/pracownik/pracownikForm";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("pracownik") Pracownik pracownik,
            BindingResult result){
        pracownikService.saveEmployee(pracownik);
        return "redirect:listaPracownikow";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{pracownikId}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("pracownikId") int id){

            pracownikService.deleteEmployee(id);

            return "redirect:/pracownik/listaPracownikow";
    }
}
```

**Run server Tomcat log:**

```
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\product\11.2.0\client_2;C:\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\app\Krzysztof\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\app\Krzysztof\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;.
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Pracownik' did not find a matching property.
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 455 ms
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
sie 06, 2014 5:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Krzysztof\workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Pracownik\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
sie 06, 2014 5:25:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
sie 06, 2014 5:25:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
sie 06, 2014 5:25:08 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 06 17:25:09 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
sie 06, 2014 5:25:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: public.pracownik
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [imie, nazwisko, telefon, id, email]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [pracownik_pkey]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@2cf78e55] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1583 ms
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 06 17:25:10 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet/servlet-context.xml]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/pracownik/save],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String pl.kert.pracownik.controller.PracownikController.saveEmployee(pl.kert.pracownik.model.Pracownik,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/pracownik/get/{pracownikId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String pl.kert.pracownik.controller.PracownikController.getPracownik(int,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/pracownik/delete/{pracownikId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String pl.kert.pracownik.controller.PracownikController.deleteEmployee(int)
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/pracownik/ || /pracownik/listaPracownikow],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String pl.kert.pracownik.controller.PracownikController.listaPracownikow(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
sie 06, 2014 5:25:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/web-resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
sie 06, 2014 5:25:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 438 ms
sie 06, 2014 5:25:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
sie 06, 2014 5:25:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3594 ms
```

My project folder:
[FOLDER.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sG0G.jpg)

Error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpf20.jpg)

Comment: Show your `PracownikController` code

Comment: Also please post the log when starting tomcat. I wouldn't be surprised to find a stack there resulting from a small mistake somewhere but still, preventing the web-app to be available, hence the 404 error.